# Randomly Login Timeout Expired errors from SQL 2000 DTS against SQL2008R2 databases

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2000, remote-server, timeoutexception

I have some JOBs running on SQL Server 2000, which are calling stored procedures or queries against remote SQL Servers (different editions).

The JOB calls a DTS, and is the DTS who does the remote connection and executes the Stored Procedure or gets a query results from the remote server.

This has been working without errors for years. I don't know why during the last month, I'm having randomly errors on these kind of jobs... I've read some other posts and seems to be related to a security issue, but I repeat, the most of times the jobs are working, only some runs are failing with the error.

```
Executed as user: SERVER\user. DTSRun:  Loading...   DTSRun:  Executing...  
DTSRun OnStart:  DTSStep_DTSDynamicPropertiesTask_2   DTSRun OnError:
DTSStep_DTSDynamicPropertiesTask_2, Error = -2147467259 (80004005)
Error string:  Login timeout expired      Error source:  Microsoft OLE DB
Provider for SQL Server      Help file:        Help context:  0
Error Detail Records:      Error:  -2147467259 (80004005); Provider Error:  0 (0)
Error string:  Login timeout expired      Error source:  Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server
Help file:        Help context:  0      DTSRun OnFinish:
DTSStep_DTSDynamicPropertiesTask_2   DTSRun:  Package execution complete.
Process Exit Code 1.  The step failed.
```

I really don't know what to check. After reboot the server the problems are still there. Any help from you guys would be appreciated.

EDIT 2019-02-14 16:15 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

One of the solutions I found has been to change the Remote Login Timeout property from the default 20 seconds to 30 seconds, or to 0 (Zero means without timeout), by executing the next code:

```
sp_configure 'remote login timeout', 30  --Or 0 seconds for infinite
go 
reconfigure with override 
go
```

From: https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/314530/error-message-when-you-execute-a-linked-server-query-in-sql-server-tim

I've tried this solution changing it to 30 seconds, but with the same result. Of course I didn't set it to 0 for obvious reasons, the timeouts are there for something. And also tried 300 seconds (5 minutes to make a login!) and still the same.

EDIT 2019-02-25 11:25 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Very similar to my problem, still not solved...
https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1727739-391-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For the moment I have a temp solution, and it is to increase the **Connect Timeout** on the Connection object.

It was blank (probably using its default value).

Since I changed this property (Connection Object > Advanced... > Connect Timeout) to **300** I'm not having the problems on these DTS. I leaved 2 DTS without the change to ensure I continued having the problem, and these are the only ones which continue having the problem. The changed ones are working fine now.